# How should I move files/folders from one Hadoop cluster to another and delete the source contents after moving?

Tags: hadoop, distcp

Using hadoop's distcp command I am able to move the files across clusters but my requirement is after moving it should delete the contents from the source.

```
hadoop distcp -update -delete -strategy dynamic SOURCE* DEST*
```

Comment: How about adding a second command for `hadoop fs rm -R SOURCE`?

Comment: I tried adding that - hdfs dfs -rm -r SOURCE/* But am getting an error when the SOURCE folder is EMPTY (: No such file or directory)

Comment: If the source folder doesn't exist, then how is the distcp command working?

Comment: I am having 2 steps. First step is to move the files using distcp and next step is removal of files from SOURCE. In some scenarios there won't be any files in SOURCE folder

Comment: Well, even if there aren't files _inside_ the source folder, then `rm -R /path/to/SOURCE` should still work. It's only when you add the `/*` when you get an error that there are no files in the path to remove... In other words, that is not necessary when the recursive delete starts at the parent directory